# Encode array to JSON string without array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm sending a JSON string to the database from Javascript, with the following syntax:

```
["Product1","Product2","Product3"]
```

Before I simply put this data in my database without decoding it in php, and it worked without problems when using it again after retreival.

However now I need to make a few changes to the data in the string, so I decode it in PHP, which will result in an array like so:

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST["myjsonstring"]));
//outputs
//Array
//(
//    [0] => Product1
//    [2] => Product2
//    [3] => Product3
//)
```

My problem is that when I encode this array back to JSON, the string's format will be the following:

```
{"0":"Product1","2":"Product2","3":"Product3"}
```

I need the encoded string to be the same as my javascript creates, so without the array indexes. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Why the missing index in your array?  I think you are not showing all the code touching this array. If you don't have a continuous set of numerical index values, the json_encode process will treat it like an associative array and encode to object notation instead of array notation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want PHP's [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function:

```php
$json_out = json_encode(array_values($your_array_here));
```

Comment: $json_out = json_encode(array_values($your_array_here));

Comment: Put that example in your answer.

Comment: The missing index might be important, though.

Comment: I'm stumped.  The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) says that the `array_values()` function "Returns an **INDEXED** array of values."  And when I do `$array2 = array_values($array1)`, both arrays continue to contain indexes of this format: `[0] =>`

Comment: An indexed array is an array that is numerically indexed.  Per manual, "array_values() returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically."  Or do you mean that all the values are empty/blank?

Comment: Is there any way to encode the array without numerical indexes, or any indexes at all?

Something like this:
`{
  "id": 1,
  "geometry": [
     15.12412412412,
     22.12431241241
   ]
 }`

Comment: Well, PHP has to keep track of array members *somehow*, so, no, an array without indexes can't (doesn't?) exist.  But getting your desired result is easy enough: ```$geometry = [15.12412412412, 22.1243124124];

$myarray  = [
        'id' => 1,
        'geometry' => $geometry
];

echo json_encode($myarray);```